# Convert a Based-n Number To Decimal But Doesn't Work

Tags: c, pow

I tried to convert a number n-based to decimal with C. I have this code :

```
scanf("%d", &n);
scanf("%d %d %d %d", &n1, &n2, &n3, &n4);

dec = ( n1*pow(n,3) + n2*pow(n,2) + n3*pow(n,1) + n4*pow(n,0) );
```

It works fine until I enter n=10 & n1 n2 n3 n4=0 2 5 4.

The result should be 254, but the terminal showed 253. It turns out that starting from 200-999, the `dec` decreased by 1. However when I input 1000, the `dec=1000`. How can I fix this?

Comment: Why is this question tagged both [tag:c] and [tag:c#]?

Comment: Works for me. @Hikmah Az which machine are you using

Comment: `pow` uses doubles, so you might have rounding issues -- conversion from a `double` to `int` rounds *down*.

Comment: @Jongware It rather truncates, as in `if ((int) -4.5 == -4) puts("kek");` outputs *kek*.

Comment: Why the unneccessary `n4*pow(n,0)`? Besides calling `pow` will result in recalculating the lower powers again and again if the `pow` functions uses a naive multiply method for integer exponents. For example in your code `pow(n, 3)` will be calculated 3 times and `pow(n, 2)` 2 times. Better calculate the powers separately

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you have declared `dec` as an `int` while the function [pow](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pow) returns a `double` value. Here double is converted to an int an is rounded.

change to

```
double dec = ( n1*pow(n,3) + n2*pow(n,2) + n3*pow(n,1) + n4*pow(n,0) );
printf("%f",dec);
```

and the output will be

```
254.000000
```

Comment: yap you're right. thank you so much. its now working just fine.

Answer (score 1):

While the code you have provided works fine on some implementations, example [**here**](http://ideone.com/9G66y9), you could preferably not use the `pow` function since you are working with integers and non-negatives as power, and define your own `intpow` function. A naive implementation of that would be:

```
int intpow(int n, unsigned int power)
{
    int result = 1;
    while (power)
    {
        result *= n;
        power--;
    }
    return result;
}
```

It just might be that that whole sum, which is a sum of doubles, turns out to be less than the number you expect to see by, say, `0.000013`, of which the digits after the decimal point are discarded when being converted to get assigned to that `int dec`.

You could check the `double` result by changing the type of `dec` to `double` and printing it with the format specifier `"%f"`. If that's the case, my recommendation would be a proper solution.

You may also try and think of better ways of base conversion, because there is one which doesn't require a `(int)pow` at all.